# "Couldn't find any package by glob and regex" appear when reinstall an app

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall, 22.10

I'm new to Ubuntu and have installed an app on my device successfully. But I want to reinstall this app so that I uninstall it then reinstall. But when I reinstall, this error appear

[image]

I have uninstall app by using Ubuntu Software. Does I need to delete anything else?

Comment: The command `apt-get` is a tool to download & install a package; your pasted image shows you trying to use it to install a local file which isn't how it works.  The command `apt` has the capacity to install locally produced files (otherwise you use the `dpkg` command that `apt-get` is a front-end tool for).  You do realize you can `apt install --reinstall` and thus skip the 'delete' stage....

Comment: Read my comment; `apt-get` is a download & install utility; why it's got *get* in the command so that package needs to exist in your sources to be found (ie. the command doesn't look locally as it's going to '*get*' it for you!)

Comment: @guiverc it does look locally if you use `./filename`. But it's easier to use `apt` on the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to install a local package, just use the `apt` command. Also remember to prefix your local file with `./`. If you don't add the `./` prefix, `apt` will try to find the package name in the repositories.

So run the installation command like this:

```
sudo apt install ./Lark-linux_x64-5.10.7.deb
```

If the package already exists, and you want to reinstall, add the `--reinstall` option:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ./Lark-linux_x64-5.10.7.deb
```